# Issue adding "app:layout_behavior" in Constraint layout for collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am facing one issue since past few days. Below is the issue details.
I need to hide the top layout while scrolling the recyclerview, for that I am using "app:layout_behavior" in Coordinator layout with Collapisng toolbar.But after adding "app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" in Coordinator layout a blank space is coming at the top of the "com.customviewtext.customviews.recyclerviews.TrayRecyclerView". That recyclerview should start from the top of the layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">


    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraint_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            >
            <com.customviewtext.customviews.recyclerviews.TrayRecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/main_home_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/page_margin_bottom"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/l3_menu_back"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimens_30dp"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dimens_30dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/l3_back_icon_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/l2_menu_margin_top"
                android:contentDescription="@string/no_go_back"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimens_5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dimens_5dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/back_arrow" />

            <com.customviewtext.fab.custom.CustomFabButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimens_10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimens_86dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


            <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
                android:id="@+id/gifFLoat"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_100"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/static_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dp_10"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_100"
                android:contentDescription="@string/background_image_for_card_view"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/cast_minicontroller"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimens_8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimens_8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/minicontroller_bottom"
                android:layout="@layout/cast_mini_controller_fragment"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/rl_home_cast"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/home_cast_button_size"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/home_cast_button_size"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimens_15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/home_cast_button_bottom_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_home_cast_bg_new"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent "
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

                <androidx.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton
                    android:id="@+id/pt_home_cast_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/home_cast_button_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/home_cast_button_size"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/white_color"
                    android:icon="@drawable/common_full_open_on_phone"
                    android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/home_fragment_level_two_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/close_fab"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimens_floating_close_icon"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimens_25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimens_10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dp_120"
                    android:src="@drawable/close_floating_button"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </FrameLayout>

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/page_loader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout="@layout/layout_skeleton"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/api_error_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout="@layout/api_error"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/connection_error"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout="@layout/connection_error"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/my_appbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/home_top_menu"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:elevation="5dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/click"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                            android:foregroundGravity="center"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sony_liv_logo" />


                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:id="@+id/subscribe_renew_upgrade_layout"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/click"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                            <FrameLayout
                                android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/subscribe_button_frame_layout"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimens_5dp"
                                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/dimens_2dp"
                                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimens_2dp"
                                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/subscribe"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:contentDescription="@string/subscribe"
                                        android:foregroundGravity="center"
                                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                                    <TextView
                                        android:id="@+id/subscribe_title"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:gravity="center"
                                        android:padding="@dimen/dimens_5dp"
                                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                                        android:textSize="@dimen/l2_menu_text"
                                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/right_icon"
                                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                                        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
                                        tools:text="hello" />

                                    <ImageView
                                        android:id="@+id/right_icon"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:contentDescription="@string/right_arrow_icon"
                                        android:foregroundGravity="center"
                                        android:paddingStart="@dimen/dimens_2dp"
                                        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimens_5dp"
                                        android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/subscribe_title"
                                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
                            </FrameLayout>

                            <View
                                android:id="@+id/divider_line"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_1dp"
                                android:layout_height="0dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimens_2dp"
                                android:background="@color/dark_grey"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/frameLayout">

                            </View>

                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/search_more_icon"
                            android:layout_width="@dimen/dimens_25dp"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimens_25dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimens_10dp"
                            android:foregroundGravity="center"
                            android:padding="@dimen/dp_2"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:visibility="invisible"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.9"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/subscribe_renew_upgrade_layout"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/click"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_search_white" />

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/recycler_view_l2_menu"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:foregroundGravity="center"
                            android:visibility="gone"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/click"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/click" />

                    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler_view_l2_menu_navigation_fix"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimens_18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>
            <!-- app:tabGravity="fill"
             app:tabMode="scrollable"-->

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="sampleData"
            type="com.customviewtext.viewmodel.home.SampleViewModel" />
    </data>
</layout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.